# Border radius issue - pixelated div in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging

Please take a look at the following pen
http://codepen.io/zollex/pen/pbYEmP
I have a div which has a child div inside, both have:

```
border-radius:50%
height:35px;
width:35px;
```

But they have different BG colors. You can see that the div looks very pixelated. What's the workaround of that problem? Any help is appreciated!

P.S - I need the parent div to keep all its properties! deleting them is not a solution for me

Comment: Checked on Mac El captain chrome, can't see any pixelation

Comment: checked on both, mac and windows chrome, both had

Comment: Not really a *solution* per se, but would something like `.one .two {    transform: scale(1.025); }` work?

Comment: it worked! Thanks man!